# How do I isolate for the interest with either the the future value or present value equations?

Tags: finance

I'm having troubles understanding how to isolate for the interest with either the future value or present value equations.
Say we know what $K$ and $n$ are, and I'm trying to find $j$:

$$\frac{(1+j)^n-1}{j}=K$$

or

$$\frac{1-v^n}{j} = K$$

where $v = \frac {1}{1+j}$

Comment: second equation should be: (1-v^n)/j = K

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question pretty extensively...please check to make sure I didn't accidentally change your meaning.  In particular, I couldn't tell whether you wanted the first equation as I wrote it or if you wanted $(1+j)^{n-1}$ instead.

Comment: No that's what I wanted thank you ! It makes way more sense. I just want to note that  the these 2 equations are independent of each other (i.e. the Ks don't equal). I'm looking to find out how I can get the value of j with the first equation. and how I can get j with just the second equation. Thanks !

Comment: Unless I'm missing something (always possible) these equations don't have simple closed solutions.   Numerical methods work well.

Comment: Here's an a question example : ((1+j)^30 -1)/j=41.487451 and the answer is j= 0.0214273.  But I have no idea how to get that answer

Comment: @user281096 I misinterpretated your question. But agree to lulu.

Comment: Wolfram alpha is your friend!  just do a mesh.   I just ran it in excel...took only a few seconds.  But...it's a 30 degree polynomial!  Easy to rule out quick solutions.

Comment: By a "mesh" I mean:  just compute $(1+j)^{30}-41.487451j-1$ for $j={.01,.011,.012,...}$.  You'll see that it changes sign between $.021$ and $.022$.  So then, start at $.021$ and use a finer mesh.  There are better numerical methods available, but this works and it is very fast.

Comment: If I get this kind of question on a test I need to be able to do it without technology ?

Comment: Well, ok.   I don't see how to get the answer $.0214273$ without a computer.  Doesn't mean there isn't a way to do it!  I often miss things.  Like I say, I'd do it numerically.  Sorry!

Comment: @user281096 I´ve edited my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $w= j+1$, you have
\begin{align}
K &= \frac{w^n-1}{w -1}\\
\end{align}

We know that 
\begin{align}
(w^n-1) &= (w-1)(w^{n-1}+w^{n-2}+\cdots+1)
\end{align}

Therefore you can obtain the the value for $w$, and $j$ consequently, by finding the roots of the equation
\begin{align}
 (w^{n-1}+w^{n-2}+\cdots+1) -K = 0
\end{align}

Doing it on paper I wouldn't expect $n\geq3$.

Answer (score 0):

You have $\frac{(1+j)^{30} -1}{j}=41.487451$. Let $j+1=q \Rightarrow q-1=j$

And let $a=41.487451$

We get $\frac{q^{30} -1}{q-1}=a$

Multiplying both sides by $q-1$.

$q^{30} -1=aq-a$

Putting all terms on the RHS.

$q^{30}-aq -1+a=0$

Substituting back

$q^{30}-41.487451\cdot q +40.487451=0$

This equation can not be solved algebraically. You have to use an approximation method, for instance the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

We know that j is greater than 0 and almost surely not bigger than $10\%=0.1$ since $j$ is an interest rate or something similar. And therfore q is between $1$ and $1.1$ A good initial value for q should be $1.05$

Comment: Not sure, but I believe the intent was to solve for $j$, $n$ is given.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking on how to get j! I know what n is.